# Adding rupee and paise in c ++

Tags: c++

I have written a program in c++ for adding rupee and paisa .
My header file is as follows :

```
#ifndef CURRENTY_H
#define CURRENT_H
class current
{
long Rs;
int paise;
public:
    current()
      {
       Rs=0;
       paise=0;
      }
   void get();
   void operator+=(current &t);
   void put();

};
```

and my current.cpp file is

```
#include<iostream>
#include"current.h"
void current::get()
 {
    std::cout<<"\nEnter currency in Rs:";
    std::cin>>Rs;
    std::cout<<"\nEnter currency in Paise:";
    std::cin>>paise;
 }
 void current::operator+=(current &t)
 {
  Rs+=t.Rs;
  paise+=t.paise;
  std::cout<<"\n\nThe added currncy Rs: "<<Rs<<"."<<paise;
 }

void current:: put()
{
 std::cout<<Rs<<""<<paise;
 }
```

and my main.cpp is

```
  #include <QCoreApplication>
  #include "current.h"
  #include<iostream>
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    current c1,c2;
    c1.get();
    c2.get();
    std::cout<<"\n\tFirst currency Rs:";
    c1.put();
    std::cout<<"\n\tSecond currncy Rs:";
    c2.put();
    c1+=c2;
    return a.exec();
  }
```

and output I get is

```
Enter currency in rs: 40
Enter currency in paisa : 90
Enter currency in rs : 50
Enter currency in paisa: 90

first currency is : 40.90
second currency is 50.90

Added currency is : 90.180
```

Now problem what I am facing is i want to convert in the output i.e added currency is : 90.180 . convert whatever numbers come above 100(paisa) convert it into rupees

```
 Expected output shoud be :Added currency is : 91.8
```

How to acheive this ?

Answer (score -1):

convert paise into respective rupee and the remaining paise as it is.

```
 void current::operator+=(current &t)
 {
  Rs+=t.Rs;
  paise+=t.paise;
  Rs+= paise / 100;
  paise = paise % 100;
  std::cout<<"\n\nThe added currncy Rs: "<<Rs<<"."<<paise;
 }
```

Comment: is this created any other issue as answer is unaccepted? it do work for me.

Comment: `operator+=()` should take a `const` reference.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way is to consider currency RS and paise as a single value and round the value to convert paise to Rs and if you need to separate paise use following code.

```
int result = static_cast<int>(number*10)%10;
```